# How many of the following expressions (quadratics) factor for $n \leq 2018$

Tags: quadratics

I know that $x^2+x-1$ does not factor over the integers but $x^2+x-2$ does (i.e.: (x+2)(x-1)). If I have expressions of the form $x^2+x - n$ $\forall n \leq 2018$, how many of the expressions factor for $n \leq 2018$? I'm trying to notice a pattern because for the first 21 of these expressions I have that:

n = 2, 6, 12, 20 factor but the rest don't. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The discriminat has to be perfect square, so $$1+4n = a^2$$ for some $a$. Now since $n\leq 2018$ we have $$a^2 \leq 8073\implies a\leq 89$$ and thus since $a$ must be odd it is for $45$ values reducible.

Comment: how did you get 8073?

Comment: and hw are you getting 45? shouldn't a have to be even?

Comment: $4\cdot 2018+1 = 8073$ and $n+1$ is odd so $a$ is

Comment: oh i see, so then you get $a\leq 89$ but then how do you arrive at $45$? I know that half the numbers must be even, and the other half odd but I don't see how it's relevent to the question

Comment: i guess my question is what is the significance of 45?

Comment: The question was, for how many values $n$ the expresion is reducilbile. The answer is it is reducibile iff it has integer root and that is when the discriminat is perfect square and so for 45 values.

Comment: but I thought it was a perfect square for 89 values?

Comment: because you have plus or minus the number

Comment: Yes but, $a$ must be odd since 4n+1 is odd

Comment: oh i see, but how do you know that it's not 43? because half of 90 is 45 so half of 89 is less than 45?

Comment: odd numbers are of the form 2k-1, if $k=1$ we get $2k-1=1$ and if $k=45$ we get $2k-1 =89$

Comment: Do you understand?

Comment: Yes thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you can notice that 2,6,12,20 are all of the form $a(a-1)$ (for $a=2,3,4,5$). Let's prove that this is always the case.

If $x^2+x-n=(x+a)(x+b)$, then $x^2+x-n=x^2+(a+b)x+ab$. Thus,

- $a+b=1 \Rightarrow b=a-1$
- $n=-ab=a\cdot(-b)=a(a-1)$.

So, this quadratic factors over integers iff $n=a(a-1)$ for some integer $a$.

To count for how many $n\leq 2018$ this is the case, observe that

- For $a=45$: $n = 44\cdot 45=1980\leq 2018$
- For $a=46$: $n=45\cdot 46 =2070>2018$

So, for $a=2\dots 45$ the quadric $x^2+x-a(a-1)$ factors in integers, and there are $44$ such quadrics.

Comment: where are you getting the 44 from?

Comment: shouldn't it be for $a = 44, n = 44*43$?

Comment: @user8358234 Indeed, thank you. I've fixed the answer.